# Link tag inside list item?

Tags: html

My problem is: I have a `<a>` tag inside an `<li>` and the list have css styling to look like a button, but using like this:

```
<a href="#"><li>page</li></a>
```

It isn't correct. How shoud i do?
Is there any way that if I click in every place in the `<li>` the link will be triggered?

Comment: Put the anchor inside of the list item and make the anchor tag display block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a `ol` or `ul` as the parent, you [cannot](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html#edef-UL) have an `a` tag as a direct child.  Try flipping the two, and then playing with your CSS to get the width as you need it:

```
<li><a href="#">page</a></li>
```

Answer (score 4):

You say you have an `<a>` inside a `<li>` but in your code snippet its the other way around.  Its not valid or semantic html to have an `<a>` tag be the parent of a list item `li`.

In any case though, you need to have the `<a>` be `display:block`

Answer (score 3):

`<a>` elements are by default `inline` positioned. You should change the `display` property to `block` to occupy the entire space of its parent.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
li a {
  background: orange;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">page</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```